# Load more and combining pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

At the moment I have 3 pages and button re-directing to the next page. I was wondering if there is a way how once I click on load more or hit the bottom of the page to load the next page together with the previously loaded products? Forgot to explain that on each page I have 3 items. So again is there any way how I can add a button that will automatically load the next 3 `<li>` elements until the end is reached? Here is my code:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
    <div class="item__media">
    <div class="item__image"><a class="product-image item__link" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"><img alt="BMW" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" /> </a></div>

    <div class="item__detail"><a class="item__link" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/BMW_S1000RR_race.jpg" title="BMW motor bike">
    <p class="product-name item__name">BMW MotorBike</p>
    </a>


    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use one of 100s of "infinite scrolling" solutions out there. Google is your friend!

Comment: try learning about ajax

Comment: I have looked at them but it seems that I could not find anything applicable

Answer (score 0):

This is the other method we can proceed while clicking on the load next page option

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span.page1").click(function(){
     $("li.container2").load("page2.html");
  });
  $("span.page2").click(function(){
     $("li.container3").load("page3.html");
  });
});
<ul>
  <li class="container1">
    Continer content goes here
    <span class="page1">click here to load page 2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="container2">
  </li>
  <li class="container3">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this will be simple and enjoy dont forget to include jquery library before